# Javascript Callbacks on $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am retrieving multiple http.get requests from a server from different json sets.

At the end of each "physical" data set I perform a calculation which requires the value from the "virtual" call, this is set up in a function called "Calculate" **(see code below)**

Often, this works completely fine and the correct values are returned, however occassionally the $http.get requests do not complete in time and thus the values are still set at 0.

How do I ensure **both** http.get requests are complete for the physical and virtual calls on each "cluster"?

```
function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('http:///search?idc=LH5&type=Virtual&cluster=1').success(function(data) {
    $scope.servers = data; // get data from json
    angular.forEach($scope.servers, function(item) {
        //console.log(item.cores);
        if (parseInt(item.cores) != "NaN" && item.cores != "") {
            if (angular.isNumber(parseInt(item.cores))) {
                tcores1 = parseInt(tcores1) + parseInt(item.cores);
                tmemory1 = parseInt(tmemory1) + parseInt(item.memory);

            }
        }

    })
    console.log("Hall 5. Cluster 1 Total Cores: " + tcores1);
    console.log("Hall 5. Cluster 1 Total Memory: " + tmemory1);


}).then(function() {

    $http.get('http:///search?idc=LH5&type=Virtual&cluster=2').success(function(data) {

        $scope.servers = data; // get data from json
        angular.forEach($scope.servers, function(item) {
            //    console.log(item.cores);
            if (parseInt(item.cores) != "NaN" && item.cores != "") {
                if (angular.isNumber(parseInt(item.cores))) {
                    tcores2 = parseInt(tcores2) + parseInt(item.cores);
                    tmemory2 = parseInt(tmemory2) + parseInt(item.memory);

                }
            }

        })
        console.log("Hall 5. Cluster 2 Total Cores: " + tcores2);
        console.log("Hall 5. Cluster 2 Total Memory: " + tmemory2);


    });
}).then(function() {

    $http.get('http:///search?idc=LH5&type=Virtual&cluster=3').success(function(data) {

        $scope.servers = data; // get data from json
        angular.forEach($scope.servers, function(item) {
            //    console.log(item.cores);
            if (parseInt(item.cores) != "NaN" && item.cores != "") {
                if (angular.isNumber(parseInt(item.cores))) {
                    tcores3 = parseInt(tcores3) + parseInt(item.cores);
                    tmemory3 = parseInt(tmemory3) + parseInt(item.memory);

                }
            }

        })
        console.log("Hall 5. Cluster 3 Total Cores: " + tcores3);
        console.log("Hall 5. Cluster 3 Total memory: " + tmemory3);


    });
}).then(function() {

    $http.get('http:///search?idc=LH5&type=Virtual&cluster=4').success(function(data) {

        $scope.servers = data; // get data from json
        angular.forEach($scope.servers, function(item) {
            //    console.log(item.cores);
            if (parseInt(item.cores) != "NaN" && item.cores != "") {
                if (angular.isNumber(parseInt(item.cores))) {
                    tcores4 = parseInt(tcores4) + parseInt(item.cores);
                    tmemory4 = parseInt(tmemory4) + parseInt(item.memory);

                }
            }

        })
        console.log("Hall 5. Cluster 4 Total Cores: " + tcores4);
        console.log("Hall 5. Cluster 4 Total memory: " + tmemory4);


    });
}).then(function() {

    $http.get('http:///search?idc=LH5&type=Physical&cluster=1').success(function(data) {

        $scope.servers = data; // get data from json
        angular.forEach($scope.servers, function(item) {
            //    console.log(item.cores);
            if (parseInt(item.cores) != "NaN" && item.cores != "") {
                if (angular.isNumber(parseInt(item.cores))) {
                    tpcores1 = parseInt(tpcores1) + parseInt(item.cores);
                    tpmemory1 = parseInt(tpmemory1) + parseInt(item.memory);

                }
            }

        })
        console.log("Hall 5. Cluster 1 Total Physical Cores: " + tpcores1);
        console.log("Hall 5. Cluster 1 Total Physical memory: " + tpmemory1);
        calculate("Cluster 1", "Core", tcores1, tpcores1);
        calculate("Cluster 1", "Memory", tmemory1, tpmemory1);


    });
}).then(function() {

    $http.get('http:///search?idc=LH5&type=Physical&cluster=2').success(function(data) {

        $scope.servers = data; // get data from json
        angular.forEach($scope.servers, function(item) {
            //    console.log(item.cores);
            if (parseInt(item.cores) != "NaN" && item.cores != "") {
                if (angular.isNumber(parseInt(item.cores))) {
                    tpcores2 = parseInt(tpcores2) + parseInt(item.cores);
                    tpcores2 = parseInt(tpcores2) + parseInt(item.cores);

                }
            }

        })
        console.log("Hall 5. Cluster 2 Total Physical Cores: " + tpcores2);
        calculate("Cluster 2", "Core", tcores2, tpcores2);
        calculate("Cluster 2", "Memory", tmemory2, tpmemory2);


    });
}).then(function() {

    $http.get('http:///search?idc=LH5&type=Physical&cluster=3').success(function(data) {

        $scope.servers = data; // get data from json
        angular.forEach($scope.servers, function(item) {
            //    console.log(item.cores);
            if (parseInt(item.cores) != "NaN" && item.cores != "") {
                if (angular.isNumber(parseInt(item.cores))) {
                    tpcores3 = parseInt(tpcores3) + parseInt(item.cores);
                    tpmemory3 = parseInt(tpmemory3) + parseInt(item.memory);

                }
            }

        })
        console.log("Hall 5. Cluster 3 Total Physical Cores: " + tpcores3);
        console.log("Hall 5. Cluster 3 Total Physical memory: " + tpmemory3);
        calculate("Cluster 3", "Core", tcores3, tpcores3);
        calculate("Cluster 3", "Memory", tmemory3, tpmemory3);



    });
}).then(function() {

    $http.get('http:///search?idc=LH5&type=Physical&cluster=4').success(function(data) {

        $scope.servers = data; // get data from json
        angular.forEach($scope.servers, function(item) {
            //    console.log(item.cores);
            if (parseInt(item.cores) != "NaN" && item.cores != "") {
                if (angular.isNumber(parseInt(item.cores))) {
                    tpcores4 = parseInt(tpcores4) + parseInt(item.cores);
                    tpmemory4 = parseInt(tpmemory4) + parseInt(item.memory);

                }
            }

        })
        console.log("Hall 5. Cluster 4 Total Physical Cores: " + tpcores4);
        console.log("Hall 5. Cluster 4 Total Physical Cores: " + tpcores4);
        console.log("Hall 5. Cluster 4 Total Physical memory: " + tpmemory4);
        calculate("Cluster 4", "Core", tcores4, tpcores4);
        calculate("Cluster 4", "Memory", tmemory4, tpmemory4);


    });
});

function calculate(string, type, virtual, physical) {


    console.log(type + " capacity " + string + ": " + (virtual / physical).toFixed(2) * 100 + "%");

}
}]);
```

Comment: I can't follow your code but mixing `.success` with `.then` functions does not look like a good idea

Comment: Do these calls need run in succession like this or can they be run concurrently?

Comment: Concurrently is fine @sma

Comment: You have to properly chain your promises, e.g. by returning your $http promise. Also, for calls which do not depend on each other (which seems to be the case for some) you can send them at the same time and use `$q.all()`. Also, you should definitely use some function to abstract this - Most of your code seems to do exactly the same, just with different variable names and a different URL... it screams for a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they can be run concurrently, then fire them all off at once and then use a `$q.all` which will resolve when all promises are resolved:

```
var promiseObj = {};
promiseObj.virtual1 = $http.get('http:///search?idc=LH5&type=Virtual&cluster=1');
promiseObj.virtual2 = $http.get('http:///search?idc=LH5&type=Virtual&cluster=2');
promiseObj.physical1 = $http.get('http:///search?idc=LH5&type=Physical&cluster=1');

$q.all(promiseObj).then(function (results) {
    // results.virtual1 will be the results of virtual / cluster 1 promise
    // results.virtual2 will be the results of virtual / cluster 2
});
```

Comment: I decided to go with this solution in the end as it seemed a litle cleaner! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

When your http requests can be run in parallel, you can inject $q and use `$q.all()` like this:

```
var https = [
    $http.get(/* .... */),
    $http.get(/* .... */),
    // as many as you wish
];

$q.all(https).then(function(results) {
    console.log('All finished, results:', results);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not tailing the calls correctly. It looks like the calls can be made in parallel and update independent states `tcores[1..5]` and `tmemory[1..5]`. To do that, you can make calls independently and then create a large promise which resolves when *all* the calls have resolved using [$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

```
var core1 = $http.get('http:///search?idc=LH5&type=Virtual&cluster=1').success(function(data) {
    $scope.servers = data; // get data from json
    angular.forEach($scope.servers, function(item) {
        //console.log(item.cores);
        if (parseInt(item.cores) != "NaN" && item.cores != "") {
            if (angular.isNumber(parseInt(item.cores))) {
                tcores1 = parseInt(tcores1) + parseInt(item.cores);
                tmemory1 = parseInt(tmemory1) + parseInt(item.memory);

            }
        }

    })
    console.log("Hall 5. Cluster 1 Total Cores: " + tcores1);
    console.log("Hall 5. Cluster 1 Total Memory: " + tmemory1);
});


var core2 = $http.get('http:///search?idc=LH5&type=Virtual&cluster=2').success(function(data) {

        $scope.servers = data; // get data from json
        angular.forEach($scope.servers, function(item) {
            //    console.log(item.cores);
            if (parseInt(item.cores) != "NaN" && item.cores != "") {
                if (angular.isNumber(parseInt(item.cores))) {
                    tcores2 = parseInt(tcores2) + parseInt(item.cores);
                    tmemory2 = parseInt(tmemory2) + parseInt(item.memory);

                }
            }

        })
        console.log("Hall 5. Cluster 2 Total Cores: " + tcores2);
        console.log("Hall 5. Cluster 2 Total Memory: " + tmemory2);
    });

// ...

var allRequestsComplete = false;
$q.all([core1, core2, core3, core4, core5]).then(function () {
     allRequestsComplete = true;
});

function calculate() {
    if (!allRequestsComplete) {
          console.log(type + " capacity " + string + ": " + (virtual / physical).toFixed(2) * 100 + "%");
    } else {
          console.log('Calculation in progress.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you eloborate a bit more or point me to a previous question / tutorial?